# question on resolution vs DPI?

Tags: wpf, visual-c++, resolution, dpi

What is the meaning of the statement below:

**My system resolution is 1024 x 768 at 96 DPI**

I am not able to understand the internal maths that when we increase the DPI at fixed resoltion the user interface developed in VC++/MFC or C# /Winform application expands ( look larger then that at 96 DPI ).

For example we develop user interface at 96 DPI which mean 96 dots per inch. Now when we increase the DPI then we are increasing the Dots per inch then user interface should look compressed instead of enlarge.

I am doing it at windows 7 machine

Please help!!

Answer (score 6):

> My system resolution is 1024 x 768 at 96 DPI

This means that your computer *thinks* that your monitor has 96 dots (pixels) per inch (at this resolution). When a program does graphical calculations, it uses this setting to convert between real lengths (in inches or centimetres) and pixels.

This will work out correctly if the 96 DPI setting matches your monitor (i.e. the display area is 1024/96=10.67 by 768/96=8 inches).

Why do things get larger when you increase this setting? Let's say we want to make a button 1 inch high, and your monitor's real DPI is 96, but you have set it to 150. One inch times 150 dots per inch gives us 150 pixels, so we will draw our button 150 pixels high. But our monitor's real DPI is 96, so this appears as 150 pixels / 96 dpi = 1.56 inches high.

Answer (score -1):

there is no "DPI"-setting for your monitor, this device only knows about pixels. DPI = either printers or preformatted documents which need to be viewed in special devices. You CAN, however, calculate how many pixels would be needed to display something with the physical size (hence DPI) of X ... which is a rather unprecise calculation, by the way.

If you're calculating physical sizes you're either developing computer-games, writing your own printing-driver or need to fulfill extraordinary project-tasks